# Scala fill in blank spaces in List

Tags: list, scala, hadoop

I am working with a Scala Hadoop version and I need to fill al list with the previous value of the first field. It looks like this now:

```
List(This1, that1)

List(, that2)

List(, that3)

List(This2, that4)

List(, that1)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
List(This1, that1)

List(This1, that2)

List(This1, that3)

List(This2, that4)

List(This2, that1)
```

Update:
I have a actors and movies text file where I need to get it like this :

[  (Actor1, Movie1), (Actor1, Movie2), (Actor2, Movie3), (Actor3, Movie2), (Actor4, Movie3), (Actor4, Movie1) ]

The text file looks like this (where the | means a 'tab' to distinguish between actor and movie.) As you can see an actor can have multiple movies, where the actor will not be mentioned before the movie.

```
$, Claw     |   "OnCreativity" (2012)  [Himself]

$, Homo     |   Nykytaiteen museo (1986)  [Himself]  <25>

        |   Suuri illusioni (1985)  [Guests]  <22>

$, Steve    |   E.R. Sluts (2003) (V)  <12>

$hort, Too  |   2012 AVN Awards Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself - Musical Guest]

        |   2012 AVN Red Carpet Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself]
```

So I did this action (there were also empty lines between the actors, so that's the !_.isEmpty filter):

val test = actors.filter(!_.isEmpty).map(line => line.split("\t+").toList)

And that will create it like above with the Lists. I'm pretty new to Scala, so I don't really know how to say it properly.

Comment: What's in the first element of the list "List(, that)"? Nil? An Option?A blank string? Is there always a valid first element of the first of your lists? (like This1) Also, you said "fill a list", but you give many lists - do you have a list of lists?

Comment: There is nothing in it. It's filtered by tabs

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Please elaborate, what do you mean by "I want it to look like this". You have a `List` of `List`s and you want to convert them to a new `List` of `List`s? Is that what you want?

Comment: There can't be "nothing" if your lists are two elements long. Are you saying you have a two-element list, then some one-element lists, then another two-element list? And I've no idea what you mean  by "filtered by tabs"

Comment: I updated the question, maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your data structures are vague, so I am going to assume some things for you.

You have Actor as a string, and Movie as a string. Each row is represented as a pair, (Actor, Movie), and you have a list of such pairs. In some of the pairs, the Actor is an empty string `""`. You want the list normalized so that empty strings are replaced by the actor in the previous pair.

```
def normalizeActorsMovies(in: List[(String, String)]): List[(String, String)] = {
  in match {
    case (actor, movie) :: ("", movie2) :: rest =>
      (actor, movie) :: normalizeActorsMovies( (actor, movie2) :: rest)
    case _ => in
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't do the right thing if the initial pair has an empty Actor field, but you can add some bullet proofing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's  one solution

First, a list with the results I think you have after the split:

```
val t = List(
List("$, Claw", "\"OnCreativity\" (2012)  [Himself]"),
List("$, Homo", "Nykytaiteen museo (1986)  [Himself]  <25>"),
List("", "Suuri illusioni (1985)  [Guests]  <22>"),
List("$, Steve", "E.R. Sluts (2003) (V)  <12>"),
List("$hort, Too", "2012 AVN Awards Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself - Musical Guest]"),
List("", "2012 AVN Red Carpet Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself]"))
```

Then the code - in the `foldLeft`, we keep a list of the results so far (in reverse, for efficiency), and the value we're currently using to fill in any blank first entries we find. If we get a non-blank, we replace that value with the non-blank first entry, otherwise we keep using it. The `._1.reverse` at the end is to retrieve the modified list from the result in the correct order.

```
t.tail.foldLeft((List(t.head), t.head.head)) {
  case ((acc, previous), elem) =>
    val fill = if (elem.head.isEmpty) previous else elem.head
    ((fill :: elem.tail) :: acc, fill)
}._1.reverse 
//> res1: (List[List[String]], String) = (List(
// List($, Claw, "OnCreativity" (2012)  [Himself]),
// List($, Homo, Nykytaiteen museo (1986)  [Himself]  <25>),
// List($, Homo, Suuri illusioni (1985)  [Guests]  <22>),
// List($, Steve, E.R. Sluts (2003) (V)  <12>),
// List($hort, Too, 2012 AVN Awards Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself - Musical Guest]),
// List($hort, Too, 2012 AVN Red Carpet Show (2012) (TV)  [Himself]))
```